# Missing /opt/rocks/bin/python

Tags: yum, rocks

I am new to using Rocks cluster. The `rocks-devel` package was deleted while doing a

```
yum remove freetype
```

Now when I'm trying to install `rocks-devel-env-6.0-1.x86_64.rpm` I'm getting an error

> error: Failed dependencies:
>
> /opt/rocks/bin/python is needed by rocks-devel-env-6.0-1.x86_64

How should I solve this?

Comment: Should be a Super User question since it's not really about programming. Plus, usually there's little we can recommend when you have a corrupted install.

Comment: See the answer to your [previous (related?) question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620090/reinstalling-rocks